# drob tables their names begin with numbers in postgress using RPostgreSQL

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I try to drop tables in an scheme their names begin with digits from `R`. The tables exist in a postgress data bank.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(DBI)
pg = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con = dbConnect(pg, user= ....)
dbGetQuery(con,paste0("DROP TABLE frc_rm.",'"30062020RB"',";"))
```

where `con` containes the login information. However, the command cannot be executed!

```
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create execute: DROP TABLE frc_rm."30062020RB";
```

any idea what could be the solution?

Comment: How about: `dbExecute(conn, 'DROP TABLE frc_rm."30062020RB"')`? Can you run the same command in Postgres using the same user as in R? User may not have create/drop table privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is issue on R side with the function you are using:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbGetQuery

"
Details

This function is for SELECT queries only. Some backends may support data manipulation statements through this function for compatibility reasons. However callers are strongly advised to use dbExecute for data manipulation statements.
"